# Why matplotlib subplot images are not at the same level

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I was trying to plot 2x4 subplots.However, the first image is higher than others, even though all images have the same size.

Here are the codes and images.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

sigma = 1.1

plt.subplot(3, 4, 1)
plt.imshow(img,'gray')
plt.title("Original")

for i in range(2,9):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, i)
    size = 3+2*(i-2)
    plt.imshow(edge_detector(sigma,size,img),'gray')
    plt.title("size=%d,$\sigma$=1.1" %size)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bzu3.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you make the subplot for your plot titled "original", you use a 3x4 grid instead of 2x4 which you use in your loop. That is why the first plot does not align with the other plots. Changing your `plt.subplot(3, 4, 1)` to `plt.subplot(2, 4, 1)` solves your problem and gives you a figure with 2x4 aligned plots.

Comment: Thank you! I did not even notice that.